# Python: can I use __getitem__ instead of __next__ and __iter__

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

```
class Demo1:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.__list = list(args)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__list)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.__list[index]


class Demo2:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.__list = list(args)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__list)

    def __iter__(self):
        self.i = -1
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.i < len(self.__list):
            self.i += 1
            return self.__list[self.i]
        raise StopIteration
```

If I only use `__getitem__`, when I want to iterative Demo1 object, smartly python can work well; I can also use `__iter__` and `__next__` to implement the "iterator interface", then iterative Demo2 object.

So what is the difference between these two approaches?

Comment: Yes, you can use `__getitem__` instead of `__iter__`.

Comment: Side note: `Demo2` has a really poorly implemented `__iter__` and `__next__`. Try creating (and using) two `Demo2` iterators at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, a better implementation of `__iter__` for `Demo2` would just be `return iter(self.__list)`